# shell script. how to remove the middle of the text using sed?

Tags: shell, sed

I have filename `1_1.lot.01-APR-2014-07:17.asc_19` . I want remove the time stamp only not the extension. for example, become this after sed `1_1.lot.asc_19`

how to do it?

Comment: `echo 1_1.lot.01-APR-2014-07:17.asc_19 | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/' ` but this remove the extension.

Comment: try this `echo 1_1.lot.01-APR-2014-07:17.asc_19 | sed 's/\(.*\.\)\(\d*.*\.\)\(asc.*\)/\1\3/'` . May not be the best solution, you can improve on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the time stamp

```
sed 's/[^.]*\(\.[^.]*\)$/\1/'
```

Explanation:

- selection

  - end of line (`$` at the end) is the reference to take the pattern so read the regex from the end for understanding
  - `\.[^.]*` is the biggest content that start with dot (`\.` escaped due to meta character `.`) and that does not content a dot (`[^.]*`) until next reference (end in this case). In this case it give your extension
  - `\(   \)` is to group and keep the content in memory
  - `[^.]*`, as earlier, biggest content without dot (your date in this case)
- substitution by

  - `\1` is the content of memory slot 1 (first group in search) that is the extension in this case. Date is not included so removed in fact.

also changing the ext *asc* to *gdf*

```
sed 's/[^.]*\.asc\([^.]*\)$/.gdf\1/'
```

Comment: hi.. can you explain to how you come up with this?  im still new with sed. thanks

Comment: added comment in post

Answer (score 1):

Remove the time stamp

```
     sed  's#\(1_1\.lot\)\(.*\)\(\.asc_19\)#\1\3#'

                  (or)

     sed   's/\([^\.]\+[^\.]\+\).*\(\..*\)/\1\2/'
```

Comment: thanks.. hi..is there any way to replace the .asc to .gdf after execute sed?

Comment: Replace the pattern the like this   sed  's#\(1_1\.lot\)\(.*\)\(\.asc\)\(.*\)#\1.gdf\4#'

Comment: Please try this also    sed   's/\([^\.]\+[^\.]\+\).*\(\.asc\)\(.*\)/\1.gpf\3/'

Answer (score 0):

Try this `awk` version

```
awk  -F"."  '{print $1"."$2"."$4}' FileName
```

replace extension

```
awk  -F"."  '{print $1"."$2".gdf"}' FileName
```

**Output :**

```
1_1.lot.asc_19
```

`Sed` version removed only timestamps

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{2\}-[A-Z]\+[^.]\+.//' FileName
```